# find struct as value in std::map

Tags: c++

I am trying to use **`std::map::count()`** to find a value, which is a custom struct, in the dictionary. The following code will not compile

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}MyStruct;

MyStruct instace;
instace.x = 0;
instace.y = 1;

map<unsigned int, myStruct> myMap;
myMap[0] = instace;
if(myMap.count(instace) == 1)
{
    //do something
}
```

and this is the error I get

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::count 
[with _Kty=unsigned int, _Ty=myStruct, _Pr=std::less<unsigned int>, 
_Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, myStruct>>]" matches the 
argument list
```

I think the compiler does not know how to compare my struct. The third argument in the declaration of a map takes a compare function, I tried to create a compare function and pass it to the third argument in declaration like the following

```
struct comparer 
{
    bool operator()(MyStruct const& Left, MyStruct const& Right) const {
    return (Left.x == Right.x && Left.y == Right.y);
    }
};

map<unsigned int, myStruct, comparer> myMap;
```

but when I do **`myMap.count()`**, I get similar error.

I have searched google using every possible way I could describe the problem, but I did not find the answer. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: `map::count` takes a key, not a value. You can look up entries in `myMap` by their key of type `unsigned int`. If you want to treat `MyStruct` as a key, then it should be the first template parameter of `std::map`. What do you want to map to what else?

Comment: Oh, I got something fundamentally wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You can still iterate over the entire map, but there may be more than 1 matches.

Comment: @user1095108 because the comparer gives ambiguous relationship to the struct instances? It actually gave me a run time error. I am trying to glue the two numbers in the struct together before doing comparison. I think this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [std::map::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count), count takes the key and return the number of elements associated with that key. That means that your code should be:

```
if(myMap.count(0) == 1)  // for key == 0
```